# oneDrive for business - Deamon Application authentication not working

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, onedrive

[permissions configured in AAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DBb8.jpg) 
I'm new to Azure and onedrive for business. I'm developing a tool which gets data and posts to **onedrive for business** account using ***java***. My problem is this tools doesn't have user consent. So, I need to go for Deamon application flow/service to service application (Client credentials flow) described in oauth 2.0 specification.
First thing which i need to know is whether Deamon application and service to service application is same?

Second, when i tried as described by above documentation, i can get access token and when i'm trying to access oneDrive for business API, it's showing **Unsupported app only token.** which response code **401 UnAuthorized**. Does any one tried this. if yes can you please provide detailed instructions.

Third, I also tried to do certificate based authentication as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365), but was not successful. I managed to create certificate and update manifest. But I couldn't get to know how to authenticate based on this procedure. If any one worked on this, help me out!?

Comment: You definitely need to use a certificate for OneDrive for Business to accept the app-only token. Are you using some form of auth library to do the oauth dance at the moment, or are you trying to make the requests yourself?

Comment: yes I was using a certificate, but could not find any clear documentation how to access one drive for business using this certificate!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, per my experience, I think Deamon application should be a kind of service-to-service application, but not same. The reason comes from the second sentence below at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx.

> In this scenario, the client is typically a middle-tier web service, a daemon service, or web site.

For the second & third question, you can refer to the doc [OneDrive for Business authentication and sign in](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm) to register your app with AAD and authenticate via OAuth2.

If you got any error in the authentication process, you can find the explain for the error code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645540.aspx.

For example, the `401 UnAuthorized` error code explained by the section `Error Codes` of [Authorization Endpoint Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645544.aspx).

> **unauthorized_client**
>
> The client application is not permitted to request an authorization code.
>
> This usually occurs when the client application is not registered in Azure AD or is not added to the user's Azure AD tenant. The application can prompt the user with instruction for installing the application and adding it to Azure AD. For more information, see [Application Access](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis/).

So please check your application registed on AAD and make sure the OneDrive for Business permission has been added.

---

update for screenshot as example for adding the permission for your application on AAD.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, i have added application as shown in the [documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm#register-your-app-for-onedrive-for-business) and still gets the same exception - **Unsupported app only token**.

Comment: @PradeepNeerukonda Did you add the permission of Offical 365 Management APIs in the CONFIGURE tab of the application on your AAD tenant? I update my answer for the screenshot as example.

Comment: can you suggest any example or so for _**non - user consent**_ appplication flow.

Comment: yes i have added. please check the image attached in question.

Comment: does this client credentials flow described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) work for **One Drive for business**.??

Comment: Is there any clear documentation for step by step instructions for client credentials flow for onedrive for business? and how how do an individual user authenticated using client credentials??

Comment: @PradeepNeerukonda There is the doc [OneDrive for Business authentication and sign in](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm).

Comment: Pan, thank you for providing the doc. But, my application cannot have user to fill consent. I want details to use non user consent flow. I have followed a blog and found out a way to authenticate using client credentials flow provided by oAuth 2.0 specification. But for using that process, I need to provide a client assertion. Could help me find out how to generate client assertion using X.509 certificate.

Comment: And I have a small doubt regarding this oAuth client credential flow -- this flow directly uses client id and secret/assertion to authenticate azure and gives me access token. But in thus flow how a user is authorized or how can I get a specific user data?

Comment: @PradeepNeerukonda It seems that you need to [Use a SAML 2.0 identity provider to implement single sign-on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn641269.aspx).